# Toggle an event on marking a checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have two checkboxes. each one have a sub form that is disable when the checkbox isn't marked. i want on marking each checkbox its sub form get enabled.

I try this code but this works even the checkbox is not checked:

```
$("#form1").click(function(){
    if(":checked",this) { ..... }

 });

 $("#form2").click(function(){
    if(":checked",this) { ..... }

 });
```

would you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method:

```
if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    //It's checked!
}
```

What you have currently will always evaluate to true, because `this` will always be something truthy (not `undefined` or `null` for example).

Note that you need to pass `this` into jQuery because it will be a reference to the clicked DOM element itself, not a jQuery-wrapped element.

Answer (score 2):

Are #form1 and #form2 checkboxes? then you could do:

```
$("#form1").change(function(){
    if( this.checked ) { 
     .....
    }

 });

 $("#form2").change(function(){
    if( this.checked ) {
     ...
    }
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9pgmN/1/ (just a demo)

jQuery's `":checked"` after various redundant object building and selector filtering comes down to

```
checked: function( elem ) {
    return elem.checked === true;
}
```